# Redux. How to store the same data for two unrelated components and avoid conflicts

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two components - Component A and Component B.

Component A:

- fetches items using some API
- puts retrieved items in Redux store, lets say to items property in application state object
- displays the count of items

Component B:

- fetches items using the same API, but providing paging information (so there's server side pagination)
- puts retrieved items in Redux store to the same items property in application state object
- displays retrieved items in the list

User scenario:

Step 1. User opens Component A.

Step 2. User goes to Component B.

As both components share the same property in application state object, once a user opens Component B - he immediately sees items fetched previously by Component A as they are in the store. The Component B starts fetching the items and re-renders itself upon data retrieval. So the displaying of items produced by Component A fetch is unwanted.

The goal here is to decouple two user scenarios - working with Component A and with Component B - and stop components affecting each other.

If I create two separate properties in app state object - it would be against Redux best practices, the data will be denormalized. Let's say two properties - appState.itemsCount and appState.items.

I I have one property - the components affect each other.

Please advise the best practices on how to handle such situations.

Comment: Why do you store `items` when component A fetches them? You said it only displays the `itemsCount`, why not just store that? Then component B can use `items` without it conflicting with component A.